# Is it possible to play/pause the current chromecast media stream by a generic Android app?

Tags: android, streaming, controls, chromecast

I can't find a way to do this. is it possible to control the media stream that is current playing on chromecast, like youtube, video app, music app, or whatever from a generic Android application?

I've tried many ways to do it, but I had no success. I'm able to join the chromecast while it's playing a video from youtube for example and get it's session id and some other info, but I can't play/pause the streaming. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends on the application that is running on the receiver; not all applications use the Media namespace (from the Cast SDK) for control; if they don't, you will not be able to do anything of the sort that you are trying to do. If they do, then you should be able to send control commands.

Comment: Thank you very much Ali Naddaf. Ok, so I can control those applications that use the default namespace. Do you have any example or can give me a clue on how to do this please?? I've found many examples showing how to control the streaming for videos that we have launched on the same apk, but I can't find an example on how to control the video that other application is streaming. Can you give me a help please?

Comment: When you join a running application, you should be able to just call pause and play on RemoteMediaPlayer, after setting one up.

Comment: Thank you again Ali Naddaf, now I'm able to play/pause the stream. Is it possible to move forward or backward on a music playlist? I can seek the track, but can I change the current music? Thanks again!

Comment: No, there is no generic API for playlist so you cannot do anything generic.