# How can I connect to a Chromecast streaming via React Native and Play/Pause it?

Tags: ios, react-native, streaming, chromecast

I'm currently developing an iOS app with React Native. I can connect to my Chromecast device and stream things, but what I need is to interact with a Chromecast streaming (Youtube, Netflix, Hulu, whatever), and Play/Pause it.

Has someone achieved this?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I'm using this package to connect to my Chromecast: https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast

Comment: How are you connecting to your Chromecast? Are you using an external package?

Comment: @David I'm ussing https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast. I'll update the question.

Comment: Can't you use `Chromecast.togglePauseCast()` from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding you can only pause your media. I do not believe you can pause the stream of a 3rd party in the same way that the Google Home app does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the [Using the Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) for streaming functionalities.

Playing and Pausing videos through Chromecast has been done before, in Youtube for example according to this [TechCrunch blog](https://techcrunch.com/2015/03/16/chromecast-now-lets-you-pause-and-play-with-your-tv-remote/) but it also says that it doesn't support all kinds of streaming.

You may also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968959/is-it-possible-to-play-pause-the-current-chromecast-media-stream-by-a-generic-an) for additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some sort of global state parameter to hold whether the player pauses when chromecast is started using the GoogleCast.SESSION_STARTED listener.

On the chromecast picker once media is being cast you have a pause and volume button.